# data frame rows separated by semicolon, how do I subtract numbers and add to new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have a data frame where my rows in one column have numbers separated by a semicolon. How do I subtract the first number from the last number and add that value to a new column? Say my data frame looks like this below:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("1;2;3","1;1;1;1"),y=c(5,5))
```

How do I add a new column of the subtracted values from `x`? So the new data frame looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("1;2;3","1;1;1;1"),y=c(5,5),z=c(2,0))
```

Comment: That is no valid R code. Please clarify on `x=c(1;2;3,1;1;1;1)`.

Comment: Could you try running your example data frame producing code in the console? It produces a syntax error. Do you mean `x=c("1;2;3", "1;1;1;1")`? The values must be in a character vector, not a numeric vector if they contain semicolons

Comment: Yes, x is a character vector. I edited the question to show that.

Comment: Subtract the first number from the string in each row from the last, so `z=3-1` for the first row and `z=1-1` for second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `stringr`. The first regular expression takes the last number from the string and the second one takes the first number and then you can just subtract them.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("1;2;3","1;1;1:1"
                     ),y=c(5,5),z=c(2,0))

library(stringr)
df$eval <-   as.numeric(str_extract(df$x,"(\\d+$)")) -
             as.numeric(str_extract(df$x,"[0-9]+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most (and somehow redundant) base R code I can think of:

```
# last - first
df$z = as.numeric(substr(df$x, nchar(df$x), nchar(df$x))) -
  as.numeric(substr(df$x, 1, 1))
```

which gives

```
> df$z
[1] 2  0
```

We assume here that there is always a digit at the start and end of each string.

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("1;2;3", "1;1;1;1"), 
                 y = c(5,5))
```

Comment: wrapping it in abs is a strong assumption the op only wants the distance from each other with no signs. perhaps they can clarify. It seems from their last comment  in the question they want last number subtracted from first number.